# Jenkin build UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, ubuntu, jenkins

I'm working on a project which is based on Spring Boot ( 2.3.8 ) . It's working fine when i build in my local environment . But I'm getting `UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name` when i build the same app through jenkins.

Local Env :

- java version "1.8.0_281"
- maven 3.6.3
- Windows 10

Server Env :

- openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
- maven 3.6.0
- Ubutnu 16

Answer (score 0):

The UnsatisfiedDependencyException  means that you are missing injecting a Dependency in one of your Components. When using @Autowired or Constructor based injection you need to initialize all the beans that you wish to Autowire in a Service or a Component.

In your case since its working on you local means that Jenkins is having a different profile running than that on your local. Check what profile are you starting the App on local. If its tests that are failing in Jenkins then check running on local with the tests profile in spring.

Comment: Thanks, But I have only one profile ( spring.profiles.active=dev ).

Comment: Do you have an example of the code that you are running ? Sounds like  you are running an integration test in the jenkins build, right ?

Comment: yes. i have compared both jar with JD GUI,  Working jar has m2e.projectName,
m2e.projectLocation  property in pom.properties.